# Applying tabyl function to multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, janitor

I have a data frame similar to:

```
x1 <- as.factor(c('Yes', 'Yes', 'No', NA, 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes')) 
x2 <- as.factor(c('Yes', NA, 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes'))
x3 <- as.factor(c('Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No'))
y <- as.factor(c('Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Other', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male'))
df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, y)
```

I've written a function for a `tabyl`, as follows...

```
tabulate <- function(df,x) {
  output <- df %>% 
    tabyl(!! rlang::sym(x), y, show_missing_levels = FALSE, show_na = FALSE) %>%
    adorn_totals(where = "row") %>% 
    adorn_percentages(denominator = "col") %>% 
    adorn_pct_formatting() %>%
    adorn_ns(position = "front")
  return(output)
}
```

...and I now want to apply this to all the 'x' columns in my data frame as follows:

```
tabulate(df, 'x1')
tabulate(df, 'x2')
tabulate(df, 'x3')
```

**My question:** How can I use a looping/iteration command so that I don't have to run the function 3 times (once each for x1, x2 and x3), and also ideally maintain the layout/labelling that I get from the original `tabyl` output? (I'm aware of `lapply`, for example, but given that it returns lists I'm not sure how to use it effectively here).

Comment: Do you need `map(c('x1', 'x2', 'x3'), tabulate, df = df)`

Comment: That's perfect, thank you @akrun. Clearly my comment RE lists was just showing my naivety over how useful a list can be!

Answer (score 2):

We loop over the column names that starts with 'x' and apply the function

```
nm1 <- names(df)[startsWith(names(df), "x")]
lapply(nm1, tabulate, df = df)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
    x1     Female       Male
    No 1  (33.3%) 0   (0.0%)
   Yes 2  (66.7%) 3 (100.0%)
 Total 3 (100.0%) 3 (100.0%)

[[2]]
    x2     Female       Male      Other
    No 3 (100.0%) 0   (0.0%) 1 (100.0%)
   Yes 0   (0.0%) 2 (100.0%) 0   (0.0%)
 Total 3 (100.0%) 2 (100.0%) 1 (100.0%)

[[3]]
    x3     Female       Male      Other
    No 3 (100.0%) 2  (66.7%) 1 (100.0%)
   Yes 0   (0.0%) 1  (33.3%) 0   (0.0%)
 Total 3 (100.0%) 3 (100.0%) 1 (100.0%)
```

---

Or use `map`

```
purrr::map(nm1, tabulate, df = df)
```

---

Or may also use `across` in `summarise` and store as a `list` column

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>%
     summarise(across(starts_with('x'), 
          ~ list(tabulate(df = cur_data(), cur_column()))))
```

Then, we may `unclass`

```
unclass(out)
```